# Obtener una lista con los valores de diferentes campos en una linea

Tags: java, stream

Tengo una lista de objetos, el cual tiene diferentes campos del mismo tipo. ¿Cómo puedo obtener una lista con todos esos elementos en una sola línea?

Ejemplo:

```
public class ObjetoRaiz {
  private ObjetoHijo o1;
  private ObjetoHijo o2;
}

public class ObjetoHijo {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

Tengo una lista inicializada con muchos valores de este tipo:
`List<ObejtoRaiz> or = new ArrayList<>();`

Quisiera una lista con todos los ids de todos los objetos

Answer (score 1):

Para cada miembro de la lista or hay que aplicar una función que recupere los identificadores y luego recolectar todos los resultados en una lista. Una forma es la siguiente:

```
List<Long> ids = Stream.concat(
            or.stream().map(o -> o.getO1().getId()), 
            or.stream().map(o -> o.getO2().getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

que con versiones más modernas de Java también se puede escribir de esta forma:

```
    var ids = Stream.concat(
                or.stream().map(o -> o.getO1().getId()), 
                or.stream().map(o -> o.getO2().getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Crear una lista del tipo de dato en este caso Long

```
 var Ids = new List<Long>();
```

Y harás un foreach a la lista principal de tipo ObjetoRaiz y agregar los valores de Ids

```
 foreach(var Obj in ListaObjetoRaiz)
 {
    Ids.Add(Obj.Hijo1.id);
    Ids.Add(Obj.Hijo2.id);
 }
```

Al terminar de recorrer el foreach ya tendras todos los Id en la Lista Ids

Comment: No me vale. Recuerda que ObjetoRaiz tiene dos campos: o1 y o2. Necesito obtener los ids de esos dos campo en la misma iteración ya que la idea es hacerlo en una sola linea (osea con streams)

Comment: Listo ya lo modifique

Comment: en efecto, así esta bien (es como lo tengo hecho yo) pero como dice el título, quiero una solución en una única linea. Me gustaría saber como se puede hacer esta acción con lamdas (streams)